# Ubuntu boot takes forever

Tags: boot

I'm currently having a problem with Ubuntu 16.04, thing is its taking way too long to boot. Previously it booted in around 10-15 seconds, but now it takes way over a minute. I have the following log file but I cant figure out what to do in order to fix this issue. I'm relatively new to using Ubuntu so please consider that.

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-9K5tqHdJPEUW9sdGsyb3EwSU0/view?usp=sharing

EDIT, contents of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=ecad285f-b614-47b5-981b-95b29a1a3fbf /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
#UUID=62C8-F74B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=9ac7eade-b72b-492f-8551-5b887cfbdc13 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=09a31adc-9b70-4b13-8dc6-6623b43398e2 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=B208-F7D9  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have 2 swap partitions there. 
delete one using gparted. 
do in terminal:

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

to see which one is mounted and delete the other one.

then delete it in fstab

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit and reboot.

Comment: Lol, I dont know how that happened.  Thanks for your help, boot times are back to normal :D

Comment: now you can use your new free disk space to add it to / partition.

Comment: Notice that in general there is no problem in having two or more swap partitions. The problem is that one of the two was probably on a device that has been removed/reformatted/got a different UUID, causing a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the log --- the numbers in square brackets are seconds:

```
[   15.039685] audit: type=1400 audit(1485495450.622:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party" pid=739 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.040640] audit: type=1400 audit(1485495450.622:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=740 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.257862] Adding 4095996k swap on /dev/sda2.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4095996k FS
[   99.312609] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   99.316717] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores
```

..seems that the delay is just after swap activation, which could be partition mounting.

Do you try to mount some network share or similar thing?

Another possible culprit could be VirtualBox --- but I do not know why.

In my system, just after swap activation, `systemd-udevd` is starting:

```
[    7.254716] Adding 16383996k swap on /dev/sda2.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across :16383996k SSFS
[    7.344977] systemd-udevd[382]: starting version 204
[    7.390723] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    7.407371] smsc47b397: found SMSC SCH5317 (base address 0x0480, revision 1)
[    7.408311] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

so it could be a device misbehaving, or a disk that should be there and it's not. 
Please edit your question and add the contents of `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: I did notice that virtualbox was doing weird things, and I decided to uninstall but boot times remained without meaningful changes. Regarding the Network Share thing, im not trying to mount anything like that.